# Make vanilla JS accordion auto close previous section

Tags: javascript, css, accordion

I found this great accordion with a very compact code but what I miss here is a function to auto close previous section when opened another one. It's probably quite easy but I'm a complete JS noob, sadly.
[Original code source.](https://codepen.io/kathykato/pen/MoZJom)

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion a");

function toggleAccordion(){
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
}

items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
```

Comment: Katherine Kato, who made this accordion, just updated the Codepen code herself. Now it works exacly as requested too. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have You tried so far ?
If You didn't,  try the following logic.

Before you give an element a `active`class - loop over the rest of the elements and remove it from all of them :)

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion a");
const remove = () => {
  items.forEach(el => {
    el.classList.remove('active');
     el.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
  })
}
function toggleAccordion(){
  remove()
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
}

items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
```

Comment: I tried to toggle [active] on the only section which is currently open, not all of them. It resulted in error :)

Comment: I made an edit. Take a look at the solution. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much, buddy. It works perfectly. I know you tried to help me learn it by myself, but... I will try to improve my knowledge.

Comment: Good :) Code is simple, You will surely get it :) Upvotes apreciated ! :) Have a nice day

Comment: Would most certainly but my account here is still quite fresh, system doesn't let me upvote :( Take care, stay healthy :-) Have a great day!

Comment: I found solutions for Jquery but not for vanilla JS, therefore posted this. Someone might find it useful too as it's very simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

you could store the active one...

```js
    const items = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion a");
    let active = null;
    function toggleAccordion(){
      if(active){
        active.classList.toggle('active');
      } 
      this.classList.toggle('active');
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
      active = this;
    }
    items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
```

Comment: Hello. Regretfully, Codepen throws error [TypeError: invalid assignment to const `active']

Comment: Thanks for your time and help.